# Linked List with neither Nodes nor Arrays

Tags: c++, class, object, linked-list, singly-linked-list

My professor gave us this LinkedList.h file and said we must use it and not edit it all. I am sure that it is possible but I am having a lot of trouble implementing an insertFront function.

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H_
#define LINKEDLIST_H_
/*
 *  A singularly linked list
 */

 #include <string>

class LinkedList {

    public:
    // Default Constructor of the linked list
    LinkedList();

    // Deconstructor
    ~LinkedList();

    // Removes the first element from the linked
    // list and returns it
    char removeFront();

    // Add to the front of the linked list
    void insertFront(char c);

    // Returns the element stored at the front of the linked list
    char front() const;

    // Returns the number of elements returned
    int count() const;

    // Returns a string representation of the linked list
    std::string toString();

    private:

    char data;
    LinkedList* next;

};

#endif
```

This is what I have tried so far with my LinkedList.cpp file. It compiles correctly but crashes upon trying to assign any variables in the new object I create (inside of the insertFront(char c) function.

```
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



LinkedList::LinkedList(){
    next = NULL;
    data = 'x';
}

char LinkedList::removeFront(){
    char temp = next->data;

    next = next->next;

    return temp;
}


void LinkedList::insertFront(char c){
    LinkedList *newHead;
    newHead->data = c;
    newHead->next = next;
    next = newHead;

}

char LinkedList::front() const{
    return(next->data);
}
```

Comment: Your professor is teaching you about singularly linked lists? Maybe next week he'll cover dubiously linked lists.

Comment: You could consider the class LinkedList to be a node. Also newHead is a bad name for that variable. I would recommend something like firstNode, since the sequence is firstNode.next = this.next; this.next = firstNode. Notice that nothing is inserted before the current instance of node passed by the caller. This would imply that a dummy node is used for the true head node, and insertFront inserts a node after the dummy head node, but before the first real node. The alternative would be to have insertFront to return a pointer to the new head, but this isn't allowed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate memory for `newHead` in `insertFront`.

```
LinkedList *newHead = new LinkedList();
```